# Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio to copy a value?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a key shortcut that enables me to copy the value of the line my cursor is in?

For example, if used on this line,

```
public string FooBar = "pretty fancy text"
```

it should only copy *"pretty fancy text"*. I am aware of doing this in Resharper with the ctrl-w extended selection method, but this requires quite a few hits before I finally get the selection I want.

Comment: weird, my visual studio does it automatically, just putting the cursor on a line and using ctrl+c copy the entire line if i have nothing selected, maybe in the options, in the language section

Comment: @cg7 I don't want to copy an entire line, only a value.